# Getting images from RSS using PHP

Tags: php, xml, rss-reader, feed

I want to display an RSS feed on a web page. Currently I'm only getting the title and description but I want to get images also.

```
<?php 

$html = "";
$url = "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $itm) {
    $title=$itm->title;
    $link=$itm->link;
    $pubDate=$itm->pubDate;

    $description=$itm->description;
    $img=$itm->media;

}
    ?>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <a href="<?php echo $link  ?>" class="text text-primary"><?php echo $title; ?></a><br>
      <span class="text text-info"><?php  echo $pubDate; ?></span><br>

      <p align="right" class="text text-info"><?php echo $description;  ?></p>
     <img src="<?php echo $img;  ?>"></img>


</div>
</div>
</div>



<?php }   ?>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666440/rss-feed-with-images-using-php check this out

Comment: not working sir

Comment: I reworded your question slightly, and removed some things that are considered to be superfluous "fluff" by common consensus (e.g.  "thanks in advance").

Answer (score 0):

You've finished your `foreach` loop twice. That's almost certainly not what you want to happen, or you wouldn't have used the `foreach` loop.

Try removing the first `}` (before the bulk of the HTML) and also replacing `<img src="<?php echo $img;  ?>"></img>` with `<img src="<?php echo $img;  ?>" />`.